# Identify gaps in repeated sequences

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sequences

I have a vector that should contain n sequences from 00 to 11

```
A = [00;01;02;03;04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11;00;01;02;03;04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11]
```

and I would like to check that the sequence "00 - 11 " is always respected (no missing values).

for example if

```
A =[00;01;02;  04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11;00;01;02;03;04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11]
```

(missing 03 in the 3rd position)
For each missing value I would like to have back this information in another vector

```
missing=
 [value_1,position_1;
 value_2, position_2;
 etc, etc]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: for loop and checking that the difference between two consecutive values is 1...but I guess there are better methods...

Comment: Is it possible that there are two contiguous values missing? For example 00;01;02; 05;06.

Comment: yes it is possible...

Comment: It's tricky to do this without a loop, but `arrayfun` can handle it in a few lines.  The solution is fairly opaque, however (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

For sure we know that the last element must be 11, so we can already check for this and make our life easier for testing all previous elements. We ensure that `A` is 11-terminated, so an "element-wise change" approach (below) will be valid. Note that the same is true for the beginning, but changing `A` there would mess with indices, so we better take care of that later.

```
missing = [];
if A(end) ~= 11
    missing = [missing; 11, length(A) + 1];
    A = [A, 11];
end
```

Then we can calculate the change `dA = A(2:end) - A(1:end-1);` from one element to another, and identify the gap positions `idx_gap = find((dA~=1) & (dA~=-11));`. Now we need to expand all missing indices and expected values, using `ev` for the expected value. `ev` can be obtained from the previous value, as in

```
for k = 1 : length(idx_gap)
    ev = A(idx_gap(k));
```

Now, the number of elements to fill in is the change `dA` in that position minus one (because one means no gap). Note that this can wrap over if there is a gap at the boundary between segments, so we use the modulus.

```
    for n = 1 : mod(dA(idx_gap(k)) - 1, 12)
        ev = mod(ev + 1, 12);
        missing = [missing; ev, idx_gap(k) + 1];
    end
end
```

As a test, consider A = [5 6 7 8 9 10 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8]. That's a case where the special initialization from the beginning will fire, memorizing the missing 11 already, and changing A to [5 6 ... 7 8 11]. `missing` then will yield

```
11    24    % recognizes improper termination of A.
11     7
 0     7    % properly handles wrap-over here.
 1     7
 2     7
 5    21    % recognizes single element as missing.
 9    24
10    24
```

which should be what you are expecting. Now what's missing still is the beginning of `A`, so let's say `missing = [0 : A(1) - 1, 1; missing];` to complete the list.

Comment: Yes, that way of indexing is more appropriate. I changed that as well in the initializer for `missing`. Note also the additional entries in case `A` does not begin with 0, taken care of in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the missing values and their positions in the full sequence:

```
N = 11; % specify the repeating 0:N sub-sequence
n = 3; % reps of sub-sequence
A = [5 6 7 8 9 10 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8]'; %' column from s.bandara

da = diff([A; N+1]); % EDITED to include missing end
skipLocs = find(~(da==1 | da==-N));
skipLength = da(skipLocs)-1;
skipLength(skipLength<0) = N + skipLength(skipLength<0) + 1;
firstSkipVal = A(skipLocs)+1;

patchFun = @(x,y)(0:y)'+x - (N+1)*(((0:y)'+x)>N);
patches = arrayfun(patchFun,firstSkipVal,skipLength-1,'uni',false);
locs = arrayfun(@(x,y)(x:x+y)',skipLocs+cumsum([A(1); skipLength(1:end-1)])+1,...
    skipLength-1,'uni',false);
```

Then putting them together, including any missing values at the beginning:

```
>> gapMap = [vertcat(patches{:}) vertcat(locs{:})-1]; % not including lead
>> gapMap = [repmat((0 : A(1) - 1)',1,2); gapMap] %' including lead
gapMap =
     0     0
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
    11    11
     0    12
     1    13
     2    14
     5    29
     9    33
    10    34
    11    35
```

The first column contains the missing values.  The second column is the 0-based location in the *hypothetical* full sequence.

```
>> Afull = repmat(0:N,1,n)
>> isequal(gapMap(:,1), Afull(gapMap(:,2)+1)')
ans =
     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't solve your problem completely, you can identify the position of missing values, or of groups of contiguous missing values, like this:

```
ind = 1+find(~ismember(diff(A),[1 -11]));
```

`ind` gives the position with respect to the current sequence `A`, not to the completed sequence.

For example, with

```
A =[00;01;02;  04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11;00;01;02;03;    ;06;07;08;09;10;11];
```

this gives

```
>> ind = 1+find(~ismember(diff(A),[1 -11]))

ind =

     4
    16
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this code doesn't provide me with the information that I need...

in this case I would like to have

ind = [3 4; 4 16] 

that means that in position 4 the value 3 is missing and in position  16 the value 4 is missing...

Comment: I know. It was meant just as a suggestion. Maybe you can work from that and complete it to suit yuor needs